# why the D-FF does not use the clock assigned by me Quartus schematic

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, flipflop, quartus

[image: Overall schematic]

The schematic given above is a simplified version of a design. But this is enough to explain my problem. As you can see from the schematic, clock signal of second dff is connected to (Q0' & clk). But in simulations, D1 is not using the signal connected to the port. Instead, it clearly uses my_clk signal. I added CLK1 pin for more clear observation.

[image: Simulation results]

I wonder why does this happen? Also, I added the buffers at clock port with the hope of solving the problem but it didn't help. In case of someone offers to delete those buffers, it does not work. I also added more closer picture of the problematic area. I would really appreciate it if you explain me the problem here. Thanks in advance.

[image: Closer look to schematic]

When I remove the AND gates it works fine. So, the problem is the AND gates but I need them in my overall design.

Comment: "When i remove the AND gates it works fine, but I need them in my overall design" is an oxymoron, why do you think you need them?

Comment: The design as given can never work because you will have glitches on the output of the AND gates, but they don't seem to appear on your waveforms. If this were VHDL with a process for each block this is a clear delta-cycle issue where the AND process is triggered twice, but I don't know enough of the quartus simulation under the hood.

Comment: @DonFusili As I said in the question this is a part of a larger design. I need to implement a counter with shift right and left functionality. I know there are different ways to implement this circuit but I need to implement this circuit in Cadence. I just wanted a fast way to see if the circuit works so I wanted to simulate on quartus. I came up with a design that makes the layout smaller. Actually the AND gates will be connected to a MUX and the clock signal will change according to desired functionality of the circuit.

Comment: Will you ultimately implement this in an FPGA, an ASIC, or what?

Comment: @ThePhoton It will be on ASIC. It is for homework. I think this circuit will work on a custom made IC but I changed the design to a synchronous counter so that it works on Quartus too. Thanks for your replies.